# Eclipse, PyDev, Jython, external JAR

Tags: python, eclipse, jar, pydev, jython

I'm using Eclipse, PyDev and Jython together on a project.
It works well, but I have a problem with an external jar.

This jar is special, has no .class files inside it just a manifest which uses Class-Path attribute to list additional jars (just aggregating a bunch of jars).
It seems like adding this as an external jar ignores this attribute and because it has no .class files, it doesnt add anything visible to the project.

Do I have to add all the jars by hand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PyDev is not able to read an 'aggregating' jar, so, you really have to add those other jars manually.